# How to fix the local side port# when making a socket with Boost Asio?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, boost, asio

I'm trying to use Boost Asio to make some code that talks to a remote system over UDP. The remote system in question is a bit of a pain in that once you connect to it once, if you close the connection (like you end your program) and then try to connect again, if it doesn't see the same port# used on my end of that connection it will refuse it.

I'm trying to figure out how I can specify the port that gets used on my side of the connection, but nothing I'm trying seems to work and I'm getting a bit frustrated. I have no control over the remote endpoint, so I really need to get this working on my end.

Here's the relevant code I'm using to try to make the connection and send my data over:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_context;
socket= new udp::socket(io_context);
remoteendpoint = boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(
            ip::address::from_string(remoteipaddress_), 50200);
localendpoint = boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(
            ip::address::from_string(localipaddress_), 50103);
            
socket->bind(localendpoint,ec);
socket->open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());

int sent = socket->send_to(boost::asio::buffer(buf, len),remoteendpoint, 0, ec);
```

When I go run my code, the remote side is reporting back that it's seeing the connection coming in from a different port# (on my side, which I'm trying to set to 50103) every time I run. I really need it to ALWAYS see it as 50103.

ie: How do I ensure that the socket is ALWAYS (every time I run my program):

LocalIP:50103  <------> RemoteIP:50200

Ideas??? I'm stumped...

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: Because the remote server refuses to take any subsequent connections from a different port from my local IP if I don't use the same port number on my end... As I stated in the question...

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I THINK I fixed it. Needed to do the bind() call AFTER the socket->open().  Remote side now consistently is reporting that my side is coming from port 50103 which is what I wanted.

Seems a bit weird that you have to open before binding, but ok.

Comment: No it doesn't. There is nothing to bind until you open it.